# Spring Boot API Versioning

Tags: spring-boot, architecture

I am developing Services in Spring Boot.
Now suppose I have developed 10 APIs without any version specified and release the code on production.

Now two APIs need breaking change, so I need to create new version of these two APIs.

So how should I create my code design? Should I create one base controller & then with every new version create a new controller extending main controller? Should I use interfaces? Or is there any better approach.

Also I am planning to keep only max two/three versions of API at max. Also we are hoping for not supporting old version API for too long so design should also support easy removal of old versions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the URL version approach. add overloaded methods with [@RequestMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)() annotation. specify the version number in the value for RequestMapping.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/controller")
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sample", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getDefaultData() {

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sample/v1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getData() {

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sample/v2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> findData() {

    }
}
```

Each version of the Web Services gets a distinct URL in the format of:
    Eg:-

```
    http://example.com/controller/sample/v1
    http://example.com/controller/sample/v2
    http://example.com/controller/sample
```

and so on...

With this method, you get the benefits of:

1. You always know which version you're talking to.
2. Backwards compatibility is maintained.
3. You don't have to worry about dependency issues. Each version has the complete set of services. You just have to make sure you don't mix versions between calls (but that's up to the consumer of the service, not you as the developer).

Comment: You have created only one controller. I was asking about how to structure code for differnt versions. different controllers for different versions? or either use interfaces?

Comment: you can use single controller for different versions for the same api.

Comment: My project is too big. Obviously I can. be will that be good code architecture?

Comment: yes, I believe. single controller should be used to handle the requests for a functionality that may be different version. It gives you beneficial when you want refactor the code.